# Dismiss ActionSheet by touch outside of it in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactionsheet

I want to dismiss `UIActionsheet` when user taps anywhere else on screen. I don't want to 
provide cancel button.

**My code**

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:sheetTitle delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [sheet setTag:indexPath.row];

    for (NSString *buttonTitle in buttonTitles)
    {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
    }

    [sheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];

    [sheet release];
    [buttonTitles release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your ActionSheet object global and then allocate it into your block. then you can dismiss it from outside touches event on your view.
add following block into your view.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [sheet removeFromSuperView];
  sheet=nil;
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: not that,its depend on the flow of above block. I've applied this into my views. and this scenario works all over same like requirement. when he will apply this then work it. because what scenario actually he is using we cant decide by the above chunk of code...;-)

Comment: Don't call removeFromSuperview. Use proper method to dismiss the action sheet.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[actionSheet.window addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];`<br> `-(void)tapOut:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.actionSheet];

if (p.y < 0) {
  [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: not working with `[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`.

Comment: you have to provide cancel button to dismiss `UIActionSheet` no other way

Comment: but some apps provide this kind of facility.

Comment: have to create custom component for it

Comment: Okey i think you have to implement [actionSheet resignFirstResponder]; instead of [actionsheet removeFromSuperView];

Comment: Then why apple gives us resignFirstResponder also as actionSheet Method

Comment: this link will help you [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html)

Comment: @TheMall let me know if resignFirstResponder works for action-sheet for future implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is `UIActionsheet` default feature to `dismiss` when `touch outside`. No Need of additional code.

```
[sheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

is making the problem I think. Change it to

```
[sheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not dismiss by default. I think this behavior is for iPad, not for iPhone.

Comment: [sheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar]; is making the problem I think. Change it to  [sheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

Comment: Which IOS version you are trying?

Comment: [sheet showInView:self.view]; is working fine for me.

Comment: no, show me your code.I also make one sample app for test but it also not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67189/discussion-between-sudhin-davis-and-user2893370).

Answer (score 0):

Declare ActionSheet globally and then paste this code after the viewdidload

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
```

works 100%